# using value of external variables in assembly

Tags: assembly, extern, att

I'm having a bit of trouble working with `.extern` variables in assembly. How can I get their value to put into a register?

```
.extern a, b, c
.global main

.text
main:
  mov *value of a*, %rax
    ret
```

I've tried the following:

1. putting sign before a: `.a`, `$a`, `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `*a`
2. trying to treat `.extern` as a label `.extern+2` etc'
3. also tried `.extern a`

I think I don't quite understand what the meaning of `.extern` is and how to access it. I've tried reading Intel's manual but I couldn't find any information online which regards what I need - I guess I didn't know how to write my question properly since I don't know what `.extern` is.

If anyone could refer me to information about it and how to use it I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

`mov a(%rip), %rax` loads from `a`.

(So would `mov a, %rax` but don't do that; you always want RIP-relative or an integer register for addressing static storage in x86-64.)

I think what you're missing is that `.extern` is like in C++: it declares that the symbol is defined *elsewhere*, in a different object file.  So the above would assemble but then not link into an executable unless you linked with another `.o` e.g. from compiling `long a = 1;` at global scope in a `.c`

**In GAS `.extern` is a no-op because that's already assumed for symbol names that aren't defined in the current asm file.**  [See the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html).

---

Perhaps you wanted to reserve some space in the `.data` section and put a label on that space, like a C compiler would when you declare a global variable:

```
long a;
long main(){   // with int main GCC optimizes to loading only EAX
    return a;
}
```

compiles with GCC -O2 (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,source:'long+a+%3D+1%3B%0Along+b%3B%0A%0Along+main()%7B+%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.952226370925146,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'1',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C',t:'0')),header:(),k:48.047773629074854,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**) to the following asm, boiled down to the parts you'd want to keep for a hand-written version:

```
main:
        mov     a(%rip), %rax
        ret

  .comm   a,8,8    # reserve 8 bytes in the BSS and call it  a
```

If we'd used `long a = 1;` (a non-zero initializer):

```
.data             # switch to the .data section
.globl  a         # declare a as externally visible, like a C global not static
a:                          # a label declares a symbol with address = this position
        .quad   1           # a qword with integer value 1
```

In general you can learn asm syntax from compiler output if you know what to look for, and compile simple enough C files.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output))  But some of the essential parts (e.g. `.section`) is mostly noise if you know what to expect so Godbolt filters it out.  And to see it you have to also see `.size` and `.type` declarations which you don't need to worry about as a beginner.

Comment: thank you very much for all the information and for your help! I think I understand better now. can you perhaps advice me on how to print the content of the register so I can actually see what's going on there? I tried moving %ebx where a stored into %rsi and calling syscall, but it doesn't work

Comment: `write` takes a pointer to a string in memory.  `strace` will show you that you get `-EFAULT` for a bad pointer if you pass an integer value.  You can convert manually: [Printing an integer as a string with AT&T syntax, with Linux system calls instead of printf](//stackoverflow.com/a/45851398).  Or maybe you're looking for printf.  [Calling printf in x86\_64 using GNU assembler](//stackoverflow.com/q/38335212) Google would tell you this.  Or look at compiler output from C.